# Execute Flyway calback and report it inhistory table

Tags: flyway

I use flyway 8.5.0 and I want that my beforeMigrate or my afterMigrate sql is reported in the history table. Is this feaseable? or is there any config to setup this?

Then an other question: my repetable only runs when they change (checksum) but for my understanding the repetible sql should run every time. not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beforeMigrate and afterMigrate SQL wont appear in your history table. If you look at the tutorial example for callbacks you can see that beforeMigrate can be called before the schema history table is created which would cause issues if it was trying to add itself to it. Additionally, I'm assuming these will be mostly static executions and would not really be part of the version history.
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/callbacks

For repeatable, no they are only applied when the checksum has changed.

> Repeatable migrations are very useful for managing database objects whose definition can then simply be maintained in a single file in version control. Instead of being run just once, they are (re-)applied every time their checksum changes.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/repeatable

Comment: It make sense what you write. I hoped to have a little chance to bypass the writing in the history table